# Can you help me to get the previous lectures of this same lecture series?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, hodge-theory

I got a lecture from the link-https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/ja/thecurve/the_curve_lecture_15_1_2020.pdf.

Unfortunately, there are previous lectures of this series which
I could not find.

Can you help me to get the previous lectures of this same lecture series ?

Comment: You can download them [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/ja/thecurve/) under the section lecture notes. Please note, it is handwritten and not written with TeX.

Comment: @Fakemistake, thank you very much